# programmatically drawing sinusoids with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, programming, mathematics

Here's eight full oscillations of a sine wave:

[image: Sine]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[gray!20] (0,-2) grid (32,2); %Grid
        \draw[black,-] (0, 0)  --  (32,0); %X-Axis
        \draw[black,-] (0,-2)  --  (0 ,2); %Y-Axis
        \draw[blue]    (0 ,0)              %Origin
        %Sine-Wave%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            sin (1 ,2) cos (2 ,0) sin (3 ,-2) cos (4 ,0) sin (5 ,2) cos (6 ,0) sin (7 ,-2) cos (8 ,0)
            sin (9 ,2) cos (10,0) sin (11,-2) cos (12,0) sin (13,2) cos (14,0) sin (15,-2) cos (16,0) 
            sin (17,2) cos (18,0) sin (19,-2) cos (20,0) sin (21,2) cos (22,0) sin (23,-2) cos (24,0) 
            sin (25,2) cos (26,0) sin (27,-2) cos (28,0) sin (29,2) cos (30,0) sin (31,-2) cos (32,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My question isn't necessarily about sine waves or trigonometric functions. It's more about writing algorithms with LaTeX and using it like a real programming language.

Notice how I manually specified 32 pairs of coordinates and referred to both `sin` & `cos` 16 times just to draw 8 iterations of the same curve? Say, I want to generate a series of different standalone waves that are similar but different to this one. I don't want to have to type in every single coordinate every time, I want to automate all the boring, repetitive stuff.

Now, I don't need somebody to just draw it for me and dump the code, but rather share and explain the different tricks & techniques you can use to solve it in a programmatic way. A lot of us aren't aware of the tools at our disposal. The goal is to show the rest of us how to approach and solve these problems on our own so we can learn to do it for ourselves.

Comment: nice question, better to use `for` loops?

Comment: Also consider accepting answers to your past questions, if you find them to be useful.

Comment: Re *"...so we can learn to do it for ourselves"*: You can't be serious. Don't you want to be [spoon-fed](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) like everybody else?

Comment: @tjt263 did you got your answer for this question? if not, please explain what you miss, and if you did, please accept an answer that suits you the most.

Answer (score 7):

A very crude starting point with `foreach` loops. Not elegant (IMO), but gives one possibility.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray!20] (0,-2) grid (32,2); %Grid
    \draw[black,-] (0, 0)  --  (32,0); %X-Axis
    \draw[black,-] (0,-2)  --  (0 ,2); %Y-Axis
    %% incorporating @marmot's (user121799) suggestion      
    \draw[blue] foreach \x in {1,5,...,29} { ({\x-1} ,0) sin ({\x} ,2) cos ({\x+1} ,0) sin ({\x+2}, -2) cos ({\x+3} ,0)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Nevertheless, I am pretty sure, you can do much more than this :)

[image]

Comment: `\draw[blue]  foreach \x in {1,5,9,...,29} {  ({\x-1} ,0)        
sin ({\x} ,2) cos ({\x+1} ,0) sin ({\x+2}, -2) cos ({\x+3} ,0)};` to make it one uninterrupted path.

Comment: @user121799 Nice idea, I will incorporate that :)

Comment: 1,5,..., 29 is enough ^^

Comment: @BlackMild thanks edited as per your suggestion :)

Comment: You only need the one loop?

Comment: @tjt263 yes indeed :D

Comment: Cool, so how do we modify variables like phase and frequency for instance

Comment: @tjt263 That part I have to think about it. May be you can just modify how the signal is being spatio-temporally distributed, thereby altering phase and frequency for instance ;)

Comment: Is there anything I can do for your call in the chat room?

Comment: I cannot type in the chat room because you made it private. :-)

Comment: It is a read only chat room from my position. I can read but I cannot type any responses.

Answer (score 7):

For drawing of your sinus function I would use `plot` macro:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray,thin] (0,-2) grid[xstep=pi/2,ystep=1] (8*pi,2); %Grid
\draw   (0, 0)  --  (8*pi,0)  %X-Axis
        (0,-2)  --  (0 ,2);   %Y-Axis
% Sine-Wave, \x r means to convert '\x' from degrees to radians
\draw[blue] plot[domain=0:16*pi, samples=320] (0.5*\x,{2*sin(\x r)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

- TikZ provide macro `plot` for drawing of function. Its use is described in section *22.5 Plotting a Function*, pp 339 in the TikZ & PGF Manual (version 3.1.4a).
- Since I define domain in radians, to argument of `sin` function is add `r`: `sin(\x r)`, which make conversion of function argument from radians to degrees.
- in defining domain is used small trick. Since domain of eight function intervals is longer than text width, domain is shortened to half (to ``` 16*pi`` and the same time the widths of intervals is shortened to ```0.5*\x` (this double the function frequency):

```
\draw[blue] plot[domain=0:16*pi, samples=320] (0.5*\x,{2*sin(\x r)});
```

- That drawn function is smooth, I used 20 samples per radian (all together 320 samples)

[image]

Comment: How does it work?

Comment: @tjt263, I add some explanation. I hope to understand you the MWE,

Answer (score 7):

Giving frequency, period and amplitude of sine wave with color as options in `pic` set. The grid is drawn according to the frequency, period and amplitude values. `foreach` loop in `tikzset` is started with zero, and the frequency is drawn with `0 to f-1`. Drawing the sinusoid is based on Ti*K*z fundamentals.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\tikzset{%
pics/sw/.style args={color=#1,f=#2,p=#3,a=#4}{%
code={%
    \def\f{#2}%Frequency
    \def\p{#3}%Period
    \def\a{#4}%Amplitude
\draw[gray!20] (0,-\a) grid (\p*\f,\a); %Grid
    \draw[black,-] (0, 0)  --  (\p*\f,0); %X-Axis
    \draw[black,-] (0,-\a)  --  (0 ,\a); %Y-Axis
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{#2-1}
\foreach \t in{0,1,...,\k}{
\draw[thick,#1] ({\t*\p},0) sin (#3/4+\t*\p,#4)cos(#3/2+\t*\p,0)sin(#3*3/4+\t*\p,-#4)cos(#3+\t*\p,0);%
}%
}
 }
 }  
   \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\pic {sw={color=blue,f=8,p=4,a=2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

For `f=8`, `p=4` and `a=2`: `\pic {sw={color=blue,f=8,p=4,a=2}};`

[image]

For `f=4`, `p=5` and `a=3`: `\pic {sw={color=red,f=4,p=5,a=3}};`

[image]

**ADDENDUM:**
Adding some features to code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\tikzset{%
pics/sw/.style args={color=#1,f=#2,p=#3,a=#4}{%
code={%
    \def\f{#2}%Frequency
    \def\p{#3}%Period
    \def\a{#4}%Amplitude
\draw[gray!50] (0,-\a) grid (\p*\f,\a); %Grid
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{#2*#3}
\foreach \x in{0,1,...,\n}{
\node at (\x,0)[below right]{\x};}
    \draw[black,->] (0, 0)  --  (\p*\f+1,0)node[above]{$x$}; %X-Axis
    \draw[black,->] (0,-\a)node[left]{-$#4$}  --  (0 ,\a+1)node[right]{$y$}; %Y-Axis
    \node at (0,\a)[left]{$#4$};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{#2-1}
\foreach \t in{0,1,...,\k}{
\draw[ultra thick,#1] ({\t*\p},0) sin (#3/4+\t*\p,#4)cos(#3/2+\t*\p,0)sin(#3*3/4+\t*\p,-#4)cos(#3+\t*\p,0);%
}%
\node at (\n/2,\a+1){$y=\sin\,x$};%
}
 }
 }  
   \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\pic {sw={color=cyan,f=6,p=4,a=3}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you like to shed some light on what we're looking at here? I think I like where you're going with this one, but I understand very little of it.

Comment: I edited my answer. But my English is not good. I couldn't fully explain the code. Sorry.

Comment: @tjt263 this answer already gives the possibility to play with spatial and temporal params.

Comment: @Raaja That's what I like about it.

Comment: @tjt263 this is a very good answer indeed ;)

Comment: @Raaja, thank you, yours too.

Comment: @ferahfeza You can (as I always do) use an automatic translator like [deepl.com](http://www.deepl.com)

Comment: @AndréC, thank you. I will try.